# Mercurial equivalent of git grep

Tags: mercurial, grep

Is there an equivalent to `git grep` in Mercurial? That is, search for text only in the working copy, in files tracked by Mercurial. (`hg grep` searches the repository history.)

Comment: `grep -r` is the closest I know (or similar for `ack` etc.).

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that includes all the files that aren't tracked by Mercurial (which is what makes `git grep` convenient).

Comment: `ack` avoids the `.hg` files but yeah. You could get the list of tracked files from `hg` and pass those to `grep` explicitly (assuming you don't have too many).

Answer (score 9):

```
hg files "set:grep(regex_goes_here) and not binary()"
```

See [filesets documentation](http://selenic.com/hg/help/filesets) for more information.  Briefly, this prints all tracked files which match the given regex and are not binary files (do not contain NUL bytes).

Comment: Does this require a min version of Mercurial, or a specific extension? I couldn't get `hg files` to work on v2.6.3 (`unknown command 'files'`)

Comment: @Matt: *shrug* it's [documented to work](http://selenic.com/hg/help/files), so I'd assume it's in the latest stable version...

Comment: @Matt: I've determined that you can use `hg locate` in much the same way under older versions of hg.

Comment: Mercurial 3.2 is required. The [WhatsNew page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew#Mercurial_3.2_.282014-11-01.29) says: "files: add new command unifying locate and manifest functionality".

Answer (score 1):

Add this alias to `~/.hgrc`:

```
[alias]
grepcwd = ! $HG grep -r 'reverse(::.)' "$1" .
```

Then use `hg grepcwd foobar` the same way you would use `git grep foobar`.

Original source: http://www.emilsit.net/blog/archives/git-is-more-usable-than-mercurial/

Answer (score 1):

An upgrade to Kevins answer:
Sadly `hg files "set:grep(regex_goes_here) and not binary()"` does only return the file but does not allow to peak into the found line like `git grep` does.

So I created an alias. Put the following lines into your `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
alias hggrep='f(){
  FILES_HG=$(hg files "set:grep(\"$1\") and not binary()")
  for file_grep in $FILES_HG; do
    grep --color -Hn "$1" "$file_grep"
  done
  unset -f f
}
f'
```

Use like this: `hggrep foobar`